# How to make sure that Windows 10 has successfully synced all of my computer settings?

Tags: windows-10, sync, control-panel, microsoft-account

I'm using Windows 10 Home (10.0.10586.104) and already check-boxed all of the **Sync Setting** including all of the **Individual Sync Setting**.

Unfortunately, i don't receive any notifications from action center or nowhere else which will notifying me all of my **Windows 10 computer settings (control panel, etc.)** have already been successfully synced into **my Microsoft account** or not.

I have tried to check **OneDrive - Device backups options** on https://onedrive.live.com/options/DeviceBackups
But it says,

> "You don’t have any devices that are backing up settings to OneDrive."

Microsoft How-to menu are not helping me either on this link
 http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/about-sync-settings-on-windows-10-devices

My question, how to make sure that my settings already synced on the cloud or not?
*English is not my primary language, sorry for my bad English*

Comment: Check on another Windows 10 device to see if the settings are the same?

Comment: @DavidPostill Unfortunately, I only have one Windows 10 device, I have tried to sign in with a local account instead, and changed my theme settings, then sign in with my microsoft account again, it won't revert to my old theme settings